# updating SQL database using ajax and grails

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails

I am working with grails, in springsource tool suite, and I am facing a problem updating the SQL databse. In the page, the user is asked to enter details of his property, say address, city etc., and once clicking on button 'save' the details need to be saved in the database. Now what I need to do is, dynamically add the input fields (of address, city, etc) to the page, everytime the user clicks on button 'add'. So because of this, i need to use AJAX to post the data to the server. However, I am having trouble updating it. Here is the code of the view(.gsp file)-

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var rad1, rad2, button1, button2;
function add() {
var newP = document.createElement("p");
var input1, input2,
area = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
input1 = document.createElement("input");
input1.type = "text";
input1.placeholder = "street";
input1.id = "address";
newP.appendChild(input1);
input2 = document.createElement("input");
input2.type = "text";
input2.placeholder = "city";
input2.id = "city"
newP.appendChild(input2);
    area.appendChild(newP);
    }
 </script>
 </head>
<body>
<form name='prop' method="post" action="save">
<g:hiddenField name="owners.id"  value="${session.user.id }" /> 
<input type="button"  value="+Add" onclick= "add();" ><br>
<input type="button" name="create" id="save_button" class="save" value="save" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is what my Ajax code looks like in a separate ajax.js file-

```
$('#save_button').click(function()  {
var street = $('#address').val();
var city = $('#city').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "${createLink(controller: 'property', action: 'save')}",
    data: { address: street, city: city },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});


});
```

And here is the code in my property controller(save action)-

```
def save = {


    def propertyInstance = new Property(params)


    if (propertyInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        flash.message = "Property successfully added."
        redirect(controller:"user", action: "show", id:params.owners.id) 
    }
    else {
        render(view: "create", model: [propertyInstance: propertyInstance, id:params.owners.id])
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am not at all familiar with Ajax, so sorry if its an obvious mistake.. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#address').val();` and `$('#city').val();` will get you the value of the first `#address` or `#city` element jQuery finds. If you want to make, let's say, an array for all the address and city values provided you could do this:

```
var cities = [];
var addresses = [];

$('#address​​​​').each(function() { 
    addresses.push($(this).val());
});​

$('#cities​​​​').each(function() { 
    cities.push($(this).val());
});​
```

If there's two address and city inputs on the page, the result will look something like this:

```
console.log(addresses); // [address1, address2]
console.log(cities); // [city1, city2]
```

Edit: To reset the fields on submission (or "add" if you change the jQuery selector), you could do this:

```
$('#save_button').click(function() {
    // ... all your regular ajax stuff ...

    // reset the fields
    $('#address').val('');
    $('#city').val('');
    // ... and so on until you reset all fields
});
```

Comment: I want user to enter one set of inputs (address and city) and then click on save and that to be updated to the database. Then on clicking 'add' another set of elements will appear on the page, by the function call add(), and the same to repeat again. So is the array required?

Comment: I don't understand why it is that when I run the application, clicking on 'save' button does nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: I see, I thought you wanted to allow for any number of addresses to be added. Have you tried resetting all the field's values when the "add" button is pressed? Also, is your JavaScript even making it to the Ajax request? I recommend sprinkling in a `console.log()` or `alert()` to see if your script stops working at any point.

Comment: I added an edit explaining the field resets. Also, do you have to create the fields in the JavaScript? Why don't you just place the address and city field in the HTML and reset their values when needed?

Comment: The fields after updated, need to be replaced by just the details of the property using the 'list' action. And then a new set of input elements to be added for another property. That is the design consideration, despite the fact that what you just mentioned would be so much simpler. Is there any way around this?